# SELECT only the most recent upload of records by rundate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am dealing with a scenario where I upload records on a daily and weekly basis. 
What is the best way to write a SQL statement that selects only the most rows of those record based on the rundate?

This is NOT what I am seeking:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Table
  WHERE rundate = (SELECT MAX(rundate) from dbo.Table)
```

I also need the rows from past rundates but only the most recent of those. The problem that I am having is that they could be making changes to the hour amounts/pay codes etc. I just need the most recent records and the past most recent based on the paydate and rundate, if that makes sense. Please see example below:

[image: example]

A nice addition to this would be to also DELETE those older records based on the same criteria. Can someone please shine some light on this?

Comment: You would do this with a partition and then sort by rundate desc. This link will get you there: 

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46870/select-which-has-max-date-or-latest-date

Comment: Sound good @briskovich. Can you please show me how to do that? I'm not quite a sql pro.

Comment: Numbers don't match.   There is no 839.   Describe the rules.

Comment: @paparazzonWell they are not suppose to match since someone could update them in the meantime. I just need the most recent amount based on the paydate and rundate. Not sure which is the best approach. Maybe a fuzzy hours match?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @HABO Thanks, I will do it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@iCosmin,
This should get you what your are after:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT
    MostRecent = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Last_Name,First_Name,Position_ID,PayDate ORDER BY RunDate DESC), *
    FROM dbo.table
) AS A
WHERE A.MostRecent = 1
```

Bonus Points Query:

```
DELETE t
FROM dbo.table t
JOIN (     SELECT
    MostRecent = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Last_Name,First_Name,Position_ID,PayDate ORDER BY RunDate DESC), *
    FROM dbo.table
) AS a ON t.Last_Name = a.Last_Name AND t.First_Name = a.First_Name and t.Position_ID = a.Position_ID AND t.PayDate = a.PayDate AND t.RunDate = a.RunDate 
WHERE a.MostRecent <> 1
```

Comment: Impeccable answer! This is exactly what I was looking for - short and sweet, plus easy to understand. You truly are an all around good guy. Thank you so much.